# Who would I talk to in my company for a better understanding of internal pay scales and next level positions?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I was talking to my friend about how I don't have a lot of clarity as to my current position, what the next step or level is, how and when can I expect to get there, and whether or not the new responsibilities I have inherited as part of my job entails a negotiation for a raise or not.

My friend mentioned if I checked my company's pay scale or if my company made job roles public to get insight of what the next level might be. Unfortunately, I do not think any of these things were made clear to me because a lot of things have changed. Who would be the best person to talk to? My manager or HR department? Does it matter? Is it different for every company?

Comment: I think you should ask your manager, there probably isn't a one size fits all answer. They should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is entirely company-specific (voted to close). In virtually all situations, you should bring this to your manager who'll likely be able to answer most of your questions or else point you in the right direction, strangers on the internet can't help you here.

Comment: @Lilienthal Yeah I was uncertain if this question was company-specific or not (hence why I was asking because this is my first job out of school) so that is completely a legitimate answer. Thanks for voting to close.

Comment: @user14287117 Not a problem. Remember that you can always ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060) if you have an informal question that may not be suited to the main site. Users there should be able to help you craft a good question or can point you to other resources if your question is not on-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a large organisation, the HR department is usually the best bet.  They will be able to tell you what the pay scales / employment grades are.  They will also have resources to help you progress - there may be internal training, certification, or other services they offer.  HR will almost certainly have a list of job specifications so that you can see what qualifications / experience you need in order to move up the ladder.

For a smaller company, chat with your manager.  Explain that you're happy in your role but want to understand what your career progression is going to be like - what she expects you need to do in order to get a promotion.